# Defining an example of a Boolean algebra (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

This question is listed in my textbook:

> Give an example of a Boolean algebra B and elements $x$, $y$, $z$ in $B$ such that $x + z = y + z$, but $x \neq y$.

Now, I believe this means I have to use the axioms of Boolean algebra to prove that expression, correct? I managed to simplify it like so:
$$
    x + z + (y'z') = 1
    = x + (z + y')(z + z')
    = x + y' + z
$$
I'm not sure if that was what I was supposed to do, but using that I was able to find three conditions where $x + z = y + z$, but $x \neq y$ is true.

Comment: You need to produce an explicit example of a Boolean algebra $B$ and elements $x,y,z\in B$ such that $x+z=y+z$ but $x\neq y$.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction regarding that? I'm not sure if I completely understand Boolean algebras yet.

Comment: You say that you've found conditions where $x+z=y+z$ but $x\neq y$.  Find a Boolean algebra satisfying those conditions.  An alternative hint (which might be completely unrelated to the conditions you say you found, since I don't know what they are) is to consider the Boolean algebra $(\mathcal{P}(X),\cup,\cap,\emptyset,X)$.

Comment: Using the little simplification I did, I found that when x = 1, y = 0, and z = 1, the Boolean algebra is true. Is this the right direction?

Comment: Yep, and that shows that every Boolean algebra fails to have the cancellation property (so long as it has at least two elements).